# Python RegEx Sub, Greedy Issue?

Tags: python

Im trying to write some regex to achieve the following,

I have the following string,

```
'\n#{ [matchclass [HTTP::uri] starts_with $::XYZ] or [matchclass [HTTP::host] equals $::ABC]}\n#{[class match $HOST starts_with ::qaz]\n'
```

What I need to do is remove the :: and $:: from XYZ, ABC and qaz.
Edit : However the XYZ, ABC and qaz could potentially be any set of characters i.e -_aAzZ09 etc etc. Also this condition must only trigger if there is a matchclass or class match within the [].

I managed to get partly there via,

```
>>> re.sub(r'((matchclass|class match).*\s*)(::)(.*])',r'\1\4',x)
'\n#{ [matchclass [HTTP::uri] starts_with $::XYZ] or [matchclass [HTTP::host] equals $ABC]}\n#{[matchclass $HOST starts_with qaz]\n'
```

This kind of worked but I couldnt remove the optional $. 
Plus the first instance wasnt removed. But it might be worth just match each [] making the inner [] optional. Just a thought. Hope this makes sense.

But any other ideas would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you always want to remove `::`and`$::` from XYZ, ABC and qaz?

Comment: Yes, however there may be an instance where there is no :: or $::

Comment: So basically you only want to remove the  `::` and `$::` from the XYZ, ABC and qaz if present otherwise dont remove

Comment: the `::` occurs in front of host also and you dont want to replace that. So you need to consider where you dont want to replace anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is a special caractere, to ignore it you must use it like `\$`.

Try this:

```
re.sub(' \$?::(?=.*\])', ' ', '\n#{ [matchclass [HTTP::uri] starts_with $::XYZ] or [matchclass [HTTP::host] equals $::ABC]}\n#{[class match $HOST starts_with ::qaz]\n')
```

I hope it will be useful.

Comment: Thanks but this is based on knowing the characters. I have made an edit to the question to clear this up slighty.

Comment: @zetysz It works. Can you tell me why `::host` did not get replaced?

Comment: @Rohan Amrute I used a space in the pattern for that.If it helps you can vote up.

Comment: Nice. Can you explain the ?= piece please ?

Comment: @felix001 (? =...) is a positive lookahead. use it if you want that a pattern matches a string and will not be replaced in the result.

Comment: @felix001 I found this link useful https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/python